# Creating a shell script that parses and redirects number into next command?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to create a script that kills an Xorg process.

Here is an example of me running the commands in a terminal:

- First, I find the process id of the Xorg program (in this  case, `2494`):

.

```
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$ ps ax  | grep Xorg 
 2494 ?        Ss     6:53 Xorg :8 -config /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia -configdir /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d -sharevts -nolisten tcp -noreset -verbose 3 -isolateDevice PCI:01:00:0 -modulepath /usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
 4247 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto Xorg
```

- Then I want to kill Xorg's process:

.

```
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$ sudo kill -15 2494
```

How can I wrap this functionality into a script? Basically, get the `2494` and insert it as an argument into the `sudo kill -15` command.

Comment: A simple solution is `pkill -15 Xorg` if you've got `pgrep/pkill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there already is a command that does what you want to do :
`killall -15 Xorg`.

You can also do `kill -15 $(pidof Xorg)`.

For your script, you can use `ps aux | grep Xorg | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` as suggested by @Adionditsak or `ps ax | grep Xorg | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'` (without option 'u' in `ps`).

Comment: grep -v grep is good to include. Thanks for input. And yeah ps aux | grep Xorg | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' is pretty much what is happening in pidof aswell. Just like the piped version.

Comment: As always, there is more than one way to do it. :-) I tend to prefer to use short commands though, as parsing the output of commands is usually a good way to introduce strange bugs in scripts.

Comment: This is helpful. What is `grep -v grep`? (I couldn't find an answer in the man or google). Also, will Adionditsak's answer kill more than one process, since `$xorg_process` is equal to the pid's of more that one process?

Comment: It's much easier to do `ps aux | grep [X]org | awk '{print $2}'` and not have to have the extra grep. And as already pointed out in other answers, there are much better utilities such as `pkill` and `killall` that do the job by matching the command name (and not the command arguments).

Comment: From `man grep`:

`
       -v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
`
It's useful not to include `grep` itself in the results of `ps`.
Yes, Adionditsak's solution may kill more than one process.

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it now. I came across the same section in the man, but now it makes sense after your explanation. I think having the command as an argument confused me a bit :-)

Answer (score 2):

Get the PID of the process in row 2 (`awk '{print $2}'`), and set in a variable. Then kill it. Something like this?

```
xorg_process=$(ps aux | grep 'Xorg' | awk '{print $2}')
kill -15 $xorg_process
```

Comment: There is no need for `awk` here, just use `-o` with `ps` to output the command name. Eg 'ps -eo comm`. Also using `-e` is more portable that the BSD syntax for printing all processes (and shorter).

Comment: This is the old style method. I miss also a `grep -v grep` after `'Xorg'`